# Using Git Commands in TeamCity

Tags: git, teamcity

I want to return the results from a GIT command in my TeamCity build log. Unfortunately, I cannot using GIT commands within the Build Steps as the commands are not recognized. Any idea how I can return the results on my GIT command? Preferably, I would like to be able to pass the results to a parameter.

FYI, the git command I am using is to return the latest merged pull requests;

`git log --grep="Merge pull request #[0-9]\+" --pretty=oneline -1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to select "Always checkout files on agent" in a Version Control Settings page. This requires you to install git on the agents.

Unlike server checkout, Agent checkout creates all the necessary VCS-specific folders (e.g. `.git`) and makes it possible to run `git` commands.

More details could be found in TeamCity [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/VCS+Checkout+Mode#VCSCheckoutMode-AgentCheckout) on VCS Checkout Mode.